# Why doesn't using "if someString in object" narrow the type to keys of the object?

Tags: typescript

I would expect using `in` in this example to narrow the type of `someRuntimeStr` sufficiently to use it as an index but it doesn't work.

```
type KnownStrings = "foo" | "bar";
type MyRecordType = Record<KnownStrings, number>;

const obj: MyRecordType = {
  foo: 123,
  bar: 456
}

const someRuntimeStr: string = "foo";

if (someRuntimeStr in obj) {
  console.log(obj[someRuntimeStr]);
}
```

Instead I get this error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyRecordType'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyRecordType'.(7053)
```

[TS Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gdgewO5wMrAE4Es4HMDOUAvFAEQBmCCpUAPmQEYCGGpA3AFCiRQCyIAJQgBjBBgAmAFXDQSQ0RIA88ZGkw4CAGihwArgFsGEDAD5OHUXHzAoCBgCsAXH0EixUmcSgBvDlCiUCM4AjABMAMyaflDMGM4ALACsAGwcAL4cFghWNvgI+hACunDAWAXocVDW2HheFFTsmVjkUAAUeQVFJWUQFVA4tg4AlD7RlnkANhAAdBMIuK129gDaHYXFpeWYALpDnGlAA)

If this isn't the way to do it, is there another simple way to type narrow in a scenario like this?

Comment: This is multiple questions so you might be unhappy if someone closes this as a duplicate of a question that asks just "why doesn't this work" or one that just asks "how can I do this".  Please [edit] to make it clear which one of the questions is primary, so we can classify it; else it might be closed as needing more focus.

Comment: [`in` narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) only works with a string literal and a union type.

Comment: If the question is "why doesn't this work", the answer is essentially given at [ms/TS#48149](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48149) and I can write that up as an answer if you agree it addresses the question.

Comment: Additionally: Your `obj` isn't a valid `MyRecordType`; could you also [edit] to fix that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe In `x in y`, `y` does not *have* to be a union: https://tsplay.dev/wQRjGN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't narrow the type because it is technically unsafe, consider this example by jcalz:

```js
function f(v: { a: string }, k: string) {
  if (k in v) {
    // k is now "a" by #43284, so
    v[k].toUpperCase();
  }
}
const v = { a: "hello", b: 123 };
f(v, "b"); // kaboom
```

You can't be sure that the object you pass at the right hand side of the `in` operator only has the properties defined by its type, and since `in` is evaluated at runtime, you can't be sure you get what you expect from that check.

details for why that is and how it is addressed are discussed in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10485
and
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48149

If you must do that kind of access, I would advise you do something along the lines of:

```
if (someRuntimeStr in obj) {
  const property = obj[someRuntimeStr as keyof typeof obj] as unknown
  console.log(property);
}
```

this forces you not to assume anything about the property you'd end up with