# Why typescript narrowing doesn't work for object property?

Tags: typescript

Why typescript narrowing doesn't work for object property? The following sample codes shows what I mean.

```
let options = {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'baz',
}

for (const [key, value] of process.argv) {
    if (key in options) {
        options[key] = value; // ts(7053)
    }
}
```

I will get the error at the line `options[key] = value;`: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }'."

I know I can fix that by changing it to `options[key as keyof typeof options] = value;`

But since I have checked `if (key in options) { ... }`, shouldn't that let typescript know the `key` does exist for options? I have thought [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) should work here, why doesn't it?

And `options[key as keyof typeof options] = value;` is too wordy, it there any simpler way to fix it?

P.S. Except for the duplicated questions listed, I find `Object.keys(obj)` is another situation similar to my problem, refer to [TypeScript: Object.keys return string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Comment: See the linked questions and their answers for the answer to the main question.  If you can't figure out an answer to your secondary question you might want to open a new post for it

Comment: Thanks for the links but after reading them I have to say the workaround `key as keyof typeof option` is not safe either in those cases, especially in the example of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76015944/why-doesnt-using-if-somestring-in-object-narrow-the-type-to-keys-of-the-objec.

Comment: And I can't figure out an answer to your secondary question :(

Comment: Right, it's not safe.  Neither is the supported [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing).  TS has plenty of type safety holes, most of which are [intentional tradeoffs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness).  I don't think this changes the answer to the question, though, which is that it's a missing feature discussed at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284

Comment: "And I can't figure out an answer to your secondary question :("  I'd say there's no simpler way to fix it, but if you need to have it answered officially then make a new post for it?

Comment: I am doing some research before I make a new post (in case it would be closed immediately like this one, kind of embarrassed,  you know). But yes it seems not easier than `key as keyof typeof options`, which is already ugly.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to be embarrassed about having a question closed as a duplicate. The only reason I know about these existing questions is because I know what to look for (e.g., I know the answer is going to involve https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284, so now I can search for questions based on that).  If you don't know the answer already then it's harder to find existing questions.

Comment: I decided to go with //@ts-ignore  (as I already do if check myself, why bother). I think it is less ugly than `key as keyof typeof options` and since there is no pretty solution here.

Comment: @jcalz Hi I found `Object.keys.reduce` is another case that there is only "ugly" solution, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string